# AS400 - DDS Unique keyword

Tags: db2

I have a DDS with Unique keyword. i need to remove that is there any way i can get rid of without changing source.
Is there anyway like using SQL on object and can drop Unique Key??

I have tried `ALTER` table but it's asking Constraint name which I don't have. To me looks like defining `UNIQUE` constraints are diff then giving `UNIQUE` keyword in Source.

I am thinking to comment Unique keyword and re promote the file. I did that and after compilation of DDS, just run program and it executed without recompilation of program.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `UNIQUE` keyword from the DDS source doesn't change the file format ID and thus doesn't require any programs to be recompiled.  However, you may have program logic that expects records to be unique that will need adjusted.

You can also use `CHGPF FILE(MYDATALIB/MYFILE) SRCFILE(MYSRCLIB/QDDSSRC)` to let the system recreate the file in place; existing logicals are handled automatically.  Basically the DDS equivalent of `ALTER TABLE`